# Android: Retfofit: gson: How to give alternative key for @SerializedName

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

I have used `Retrofit` in my project and I need to switch my services dynamically between two different base URLs that return similar responses. Only change is for two objects I will get different key.

Example (service 1 - https://url1.com/user):

```
   {
      "**users**": [
        {
          "id": "123",
          "firstName": "xyz",
          "lastName": "A",
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Example (service 2 - https://url2.com/user):

```
    {
      "**user**": [
        {
          "id": "123",
          "firstName": "xyz",
          "lastName": "A",
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

How can I ensure that the response parsing doesn't break for both of these keys dynamically?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you got an extra closing flower bracket in there, this isnt syntactically correct, and both of those json look the same to me

Comment: Could you elaborate a little. Why do you think parsing any of the responses will break?

Comment: I guess he is worry about "* *user* *" tag

Comment: yes, you are right. I have same response for both "user" and "users" keys. But I can give only one key for @SerializedName. I want to have the same response mapped to both keys user and users.

Answer (score 1):

According to the json I'm reading, this would be the corresponding POJO I would create for json like this.

```
public class Response {
    private User[] user;
    private User[] users;

    //Getters and Setters
}
```

Now you can directly parse whatever json response you are getting if it contains user key it will be assigned to the `user` field, else if the response json contains users key it will be assigned to the `users` field